# Node,js and jQuery not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, api

I have this API made with Node.js, this is simple, it just crate a post:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var Posts = require('./models/posts');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/api', function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("Error with mongodb: " + err);
  }
});
app.use(bodyParser());

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.json({message: 'It\'s working'});
});

router.route('/posts')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    Posts.find(function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json(data);
    });
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var posts = new Posts();
    posts.title = req.body.title;
    posts.description = req.body.description;
    posts.content = req.body.content;
    posts.save(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json({message: "Post saved!"});
    });
  });

router.route('/posts/:id')
  .get(function(req, res){
    Posts.findById(req.param.id, function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json(data);
    });
  })
  .put(function(req, res) {
    Posts.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data) {
  if(err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
  data.nome = req.body.nome;
  data.description = req.body.description;
    data.content = req.body.content;
    data.date = Date.now;
    data.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
          res.send(err);
        }
        res.json({message: 'Post updated!'});
      });
    });
  })
  .delete(function(req, res) {
    Posts.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json({message: 'Post deleted!'});
    });
  });

app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server running on: " + port);
});
```

And I have this code on jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/posts/',
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(returnit) {
    $.each(returnit.posts, function() {
      var post = this;
      $('<p>').text(post.title).appendTo('.blog--area');
    });
  }
});
```

Could someone explain to me what is happening and why is happening? I'm new on JavaScript and it's frameworks, when I check it on the console, it says nothing.

If you could, please, give some tips for it. Thanks...

**Edit**

I forgot to mention the error, it isn't showing the posts.

Comment: What error do you get back?

Comment: It don't display the posts

Comment: For debugging, try adding some `console.logs` to your code. E.g. after the line `Posts.find(function(err, data) {` add something like `console.log("data from db", data)` to your callback function. Do the same thing on the client side in the success function: `console.log("received data", returnIt)`. And so on. At least in this way you'll be able to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JSONP for cross-domain calls. This requires some changes in your Express part(Server). Change `res.json(data)` to `res.jsonp(data)`

**Example:**

```
router.route('/posts')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    Posts.find(function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.jsonp(data); //changed
    });
  })
```

**Explanation:**
As your datatype of ajax call made to api server is `jsonp` the client side is looking for a the response wrapped in a callback function.

> *As JSONP wraps up a JSON response into a JavaScript function and sends that back as a Script to the client. A script is not subject to the Same Origin Policy and when loaded into the client, the function acts just like the JSON object that it contains.*

In your case your client is looking for something like this:

`callback_Name({"title": "Foo", "description": "HelloWorld", "content": "OK"})`

But is getting:

`{"title": "Foo", "description": "HelloWorld", "content": "OK"}`

Thus for JSONP responses one has to use res.jsonp in express.